# What is the general term for function of probability distributions?

Tags: probability, reference-request, probability-distributions

Broadly speaking, a `statistic` is defined to be a function of the data drawn from a distribution. My understanding is that a `statistic` is not a function of the distribution itself.

For my work I need to refer to functions that operate on pdfs themselves. I was calling these functions `distribution functionals` (or `disnals` for personal use) but I was wondering if there was an existing, commonly known term for functions that operate on probability distributions?

Comment: `distribution functional` may be confused with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), cf. Paolo's answer. A more general question could be whether functionals on measures have a commonly known term.

Comment: In my class we call them functions of a random variable

Comment: @Alex These would be $f(X)$, where $X\sim D$; not $f(D)$ -- or am I misinterpreting what you mean? For instance, take $f$ to be the "supremum" function, and $D$ say the uniform distribution on $\{1,\dots,n\}$. $f(X) = \sup_{X\sim D} X = n$ (with some abuse of notation going on here), while $f(D) = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @ClementC. When a function acts on a random variable it also acts on it's distribution function, just maybe not in the same way. Of course $f(X)\neq f(D)$ in your case as they are completely different sets. $X$ is a random variable however $D$ is the density function which is associated to the probability of $X$..

Comment: @ClementC. for example if $Z$~ Std Normal then $Z^2$~ $\chi^2$ however the density function of a $\chi^2$ distribution is not simply the density of a standard normal squared.

Comment: I believe that it is completely acceptable to say that a function on a random variable $X$ transforms the density function from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ in OP's case.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a functional. Given access to $X$, what is the function that provides you with, say, the support size of the distribution?

Comment: Or take the functional $f$ that takes the pdf $p$ of a continuous distribution over the reals and returns it $L_2$ norm $\int_{\mathbb{R}} p(x)^2 dx$. How can you obtain that with a function operating on a random variable $X\sim p$?